# Should I restart the controller node and data node after changing license.lic

Tags: dolphindb

Should I restart the  controller node and data node after changing license.lic

Should I restart the controller node and data node when I replace the old license.lic file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to restart the data node, just update the license dynamically by invoking the function "updateLicense".